# WPF data binding a List of strings to a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

```
<UserControl x:Class="blah..my_UserControl "
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:blah."
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.176,-0.343" Width="503" Height="85">
            <Grid>

                <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding PortList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>

                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class Child: Base
{
    public Child()
    {
        PortList.add("com1");
    }
}

public abstract class Base : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> portlist;
    public ObservableCollection<string> PortList
    {
        get { return portlist; }
        set
        {
            portlist = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PortList");
        }
    }
    public Base()
    {
        PortList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}

public partial class my_UserControl : UserControl
{
    public my_UserControl(Base base)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = base;
    }
}
```

When I create a new child class nothing appears in the combobox list. It seems to be something to do with the combobox, because I am binding several other things the exact same way and they all work.

I initialize the user control and child class in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
Child child = new Child()
my_userControl control = new my_userControl(child)
```

//then add control to mainWindow.

It's throwing this exception when i click on the combobox.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=IsDropDownOpen; DataItem='ComboBox' (Name='comboBox'); target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') XamlParseException:'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.CreateBindingExpression(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Binding binding, BindingExpressionBase parent)
```

Comment: In which view/file is the ComboBox defined  and exactly how do you set the DataContext of this one?

Comment: Can you please post more of the Xaml around your combobox? What is it nested inside?

Comment: Posted all the xaml.

Comment: How and where do you create the UserControl? Also you seem to be setting the DataContext of the UserControl to base. Set it to child as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: The DataContext gets set to the child. Shown in my edit.  The reason for the way I'm doing it is so I can have multiple childs that bind to the variables that are defined in the base class.

Comment: Do you see any items at all in the ComboBox?

Comment: It's throwing an exception when I click on the combobox.

Comment: Can you please post your *real* code? The code you have posted makes no sense and won't even compile. my_UserControl cannot have a constructor called Reader_UserControl and the argument cannot be named "base"...And what exception message are you getting?

Comment: I added the exception. Sorry I just changed the name of the classes.

Comment: Regarding the exception, see my edited answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child` shouldn't be a partial view class with an `InitializeComponent()` method.

It should be a simple derived class that inherits from `Base`:

```
public class child : Base
{
    public child()
    {
        PortList.add("com1");
    }
}
```

You should then set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` where your XAML is defined to an instance of `child`:

```
public partial class my_UserControl : UserControl
{
    public my_UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new child();
    }
}
```

> It's throwing this exception when i click on the combobox.

Change the mode of the binding to OneWay or bind to a property of class:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
```

Comment: Changing it to OneWay did the trick! Can you explain? I've never had to set the mode.

Comment: The error message says it all; "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath". The default binding mode of the Text property of the TextBox is TwoWay. You need to explicitly set it to OneWay to be able to bind to the string value in the ObservableCollection.